# C# - reference wrapper for value type

Tags: c#, .net

I want to use c# `Point` type as a reference type (it is a struct). I thought of having a class `CPoint`, which would contain a `Point` member. Is there any way to raise the members of the `Point` to act as members of the `Cpoint`. I am trying to avoid

```
cpoint.point.X;
cpoint.point.Y;
```

I would like to do

```
cpoint.X;
cpoint.Y;
```

as well as keep all the conversions, operators, `Empty`, etc.
Can this easily be done?

Comment: why do you want/need such a wrapper?

Comment: @Xint0 Like I said, to use it as a reference type.

Comment: @barunch: before doing that, consider that **there is a reason** why that kind of simple types were defined like a `structs`. One of them is, that `struct` are very fast in allocation and `Point` struct used in drawing methods, where the speed of allocation and release of it can be crucial.

Comment: @Tigran That is true. I am not using this for drawing, however. I am using it (and Size, too) as properties of my class, not used in drawing. I want to be able to do `MyClass.Pos.X=10` and similar things.

Comment: @barunch: so if you need just a `placeholder` create a simple class and not  wrapper. May be even, if you need, for easy transformation `to/from` Point struct define implicit cast operators too.

Comment: @baruch - I edited my answer based on your comment about accessing it via MyClass.Pos.X = 10

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you need it to act like a reference type then use the [ref](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/14akc2c7.aspx) keyword. It will allow you to pass by reference. With this you will get all of the performance benefits from it being a struct, as well as knowing specifically when you expect it to act like a reference. You can also use the [out](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee332485.aspx) keyword to return a parameter by reference.

If you need it to be able to represent null then use a [`Nullable<T>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b3h38hb0.aspx)

If you simply want to access is like `foo.MyPoint.X` then declare it as a field like so:

```
class Foo {
  public Point MyPoint;
}
```

Comment: I've been programming in c# since it was first created, and never knew you could do that (use "ref" with a value type)!  However, this has its limits: can't store that "reference" as an element of a collection.

Answer (score 10):

Something like this?

```
public class CPoint {
  private Point _point = new Point(0,0);
  public double X { get { return _point.X; } set { _point.X = value; } }
  public double Y { get { return _point.Y; } set { _point.Y = value; } }
  public CPoint() { }
  public CPoint(Point p) { _point = p; }
  public static implicit operator CPoint(Point p) { return new CPoint(p); }
  public static implicit operator Point(CPoint cp) { return cp._point; } 
}
```

EDIT: If you want to have this automatically converted to/from points, implement implicit conversions as per above.  Note I haven't tested these, but they should work.  More info here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z5z9kes2.aspx

Comment: Yes, except it gets very tiresome to do this for every operator and conversion and ...

Comment: See the added implicit conversions

Answer (score 5):

I think the only way is to re-write and pass-through all properties, operators and methods, just like this:

```
public class PointReference {
  private Point point;

  public int X { get { return point.X; } set { point.X = value; } }
}
```

(The change of class name is intended; `CPoint` isn't very expressive.)

Comment: Sure, don't use a `Point` at all, but implement it entirely yourself.

Comment: Please leave out the setter. A mutable `Point` reference type is so creepy.

Comment: @CodeInChanos: A mutable *struct* is creepy (and in my opinion in most cases a bad design). A mutable reference type, in contrast, is ok. Example might be *your location* or *the mouse position*.

Comment: @CodesInChaos - if it wasn't mutable, it would be pointless to make it a reference type. The primary (only?) reason to make a reference wrapper for a value type, is so that you can pass around an identity whose contents can be modified (all other references receive the changed value).

Answer (score 0):

Create a generic wrapper type.

```
public sealed class Ref<T> where T : struct
{
    public Ref(T value) => Value = value;

    public T Value { get; set; }
    public static implicit operator T(Ref<T> value) => value.Value;
}
```