# Why can fields be used as out/ref parameters and not properties?

Tags: c#, oop, properties

What makes properties and Fields different when we are passing Fields as an out/ref parameter . Does the difference between the two is memory allocation?

Comment: A quick Google search shows...Possible duplicate: [C# field vs. property](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8773181/c-sharp-field-vs-property) and [Difference between Property and Field in C# 3.0+](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/653536/difference-between-property-and-field-in-c-sharp-3-0)

Comment: @Dhiren I have changed your title. Please take a look to make sure I didn't change the meaning of your question!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The biggest difference is that properties or indexers may not be passed as `ref` or `out` parameter ([demo](http://ideone.com/sTekI4)).

This is because properties do not necessarily have a backing storage - for example, a property may be computed on the fly.

Since passing `out` and `ref` parameters requires taking variable's location in memory, and because properties lack such location, the language prohibits passing properties as `ref`/`out` parameters.

Comment: Thanks..thats quite sums up

Answer (score 2):

Properties are not like fields at all, they're like methods.

this is a field; it does not have any logic.

```
private int _afield;
```

This is a property it defines a getter and a setter.
The getter and setter are methods.

```
public int AField
{
    get
    {
        return _aField;
    }
    set
    {
        _aField = value;
    }
}
```

This is a default property.
It's exactly like the previous property and field, except it does a lot of the work for you

```
public int BField { get; set; }
```

Comment: They are not just like methods, they are methods! The compiler internally creates two methods for your property getter and setter (`int get_AField()` and `void set_AField(int value)`). And you can't exactly do a `ref` on a function result.

Comment: All of your explanations seem correct. Just note that strictly speaking, that is not a reason why they cannot be used for `ref` or `out` parameters - the language could well be defined in a way so as to translate any access to the respective parameter to the appropriate method calls for the property.

Answer (score 0):

The best way to describe properties is in terms of the idiom of "getter" and "setter" methods.

When you access a property, you are actually making a call to a "get" method.

**Java**

```
private int _myField;

public int getMyProperty()
{
    return _myField;
}

public int setMyProperty(int value)
{
    _myField = value;
}

int x = getMyProperty(); // Obviously cannot be marked as "out" or "ref"
```

**C#**

```
private int _myField;
public int MyProperty
{
    get{return _myField;}
    set{_myField = value;}
}

int x = MyProperty; // Cannot be marked as "out" or "ref" because it is actually a method call
```